# Suzuki Swift Sport and ODBii

Tags: obd-ii, suzuki

I recently purchased a new Suzuki Swift Sport, and wanted to use the Torque App for some checking ( mostly enjoy parameter reading, graphs.... ) but my wifi adapter was unable to communicate with the ECU.

Went ahead and bought another cheap ELM3276 clone, as thought 1st adapter was faulty.

Second adapter was not able to access the ECU, either. 
Got a third adapter from a friend, which upon connected, triggered an alert in the dashboard instructing to check ESP.

Turned car off, unplugged the adapter, started the car... no error.

Does somebody knows if Suzuki cars require a special adapter or protocol for OBD2 ?

I looked around and seems this is an "expected behavior" with cheap adapters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, original adapter worked with no issues in previous car, a Turkish Renault Fluence 2017.

Comment: Cheap adapters are more trouble than they are worth

Comment: NO cars need a special adapter for OBD, it's intended to be universal. I have't had any issues with my sub-$10 clone ELM adapter on the many vehicles I've used it on, though the clone adapters are often poorly made, and the pirated software is an early version and has a few glitches.

Comment: What are you using to try and connect to the ELM327 device? While iPhones have Bluetooth capability, you have to use an ELM327 with wifi capabilities to connect to an iPhone as they will not work otherwise. An Android device can be connected over Bluetooth.

Comment: HAve a WIFI and a BT Adapter. The phone is a Nokia 6.1 with Torque app. Phone pairs with no problem and Torque finds the adapter with no issues, but adapter (both) are unable to "find" the ECU.